# HTTP header line break style

Tags: http, line-breaks

Which line break style is preferable for use in HTTP headers: `\r\n` or `\n`, and why?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

`\r\n`, because it's defined as the line break in the protocol specification. [RFC2616 states at the beginning of section 2.2, "Basic Rules"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2), quite unambiguously:

> CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
> LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all protocol elements except the entity-body

RFC2616 was technically obsoleted by RFC7230, but it makes no drastic changes and again calls out CRLF as the delimiter in [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3), and that RFC references [RFC5234, Appendix B.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#appendix-B.1) to define "CRLF" as `%x0D %x0A`.

However, recognizing that people will break the standard for whatever purposes, there is a "tolerance provision" in [section 19.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.3) (note that it re-iterates the *correct* sequence):

> The line terminator for message-header fields is the sequence CRLF. However, we recommend that applications, when parsing such headers, recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore the leading CR.

In the newer [RFC7230, § 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.5)

> Although the line terminator for the start-line and header fields is the sequence CRLF, a recipient MAY recognize a single LF as a line terminator and ignore any preceding CR.

Therefore, unless you want to be Evil or otherwise break the RFC's rules, use `\r\n`.

Comment: @Fred: No, there *is* such a thing as being too obvious - unneeded repetition and unnecessarily repeating and pointlessly repeating the same information clouds the message. Especially when the same thing is quoted right above - from the spec, no less.

Comment: Good clear answer. This is exactly what StackOverflow is best for: simple clear answers to simple clear questions, without the unnecessary and unhelpful clutter of blogs and articles.

Comment: @Piskvor, Is the response allowed to **start** with `\r\n` ?

Comment: @Pacerier: No. That would give you a response without any response-header. Since a response code and phrase are *required* on the first line (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`), I'd say that a response starting with an endline would be invalid.

Comment: @Piskvor, Does the RFC mention that such *trimming* is not allowed or is it "optional"?

Comment: @Pacerier: Does not mention any such thing at all; since it essentially specifies "this is the only valid syntax for HTTP," anything else is invalid syntax. Of course, you *could* violate the RFC all you want, there's nobody who could stop you - but then you're technically not implementing a HTTP client anymore, just something that looks sort of similar ;)

Comment: IMHO, would be interesting to know WHY `\r\n` was chosen instead of other options (`\r`, `\n`, something else).

Comment: RFC7230 which obsoletes RFC2616 contains the same text in [Section 3.5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.5)

Comment: @Grief: Still proposed only, and didn't exist when this answer was written. Good catch nevertheless! :)

Comment: CRLF is not for Microsoft.
For the history of the topic see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262779/why-does-http-use-crlf-as-line-delimiter

Answer (score 30):

`\r\n` because RFC 2616 says so (Section 2.2, "Basic Rules"):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF
> as the end-of-line marker for all
> protocol elements except the
> entity-body (see appendix 19.3 for
> tolerant applications). The
> end-of-line marker within an
> entity-body    is defined by its
> associated media type, as described in
> section 3.7.
>
> ```
>    CRLF           = CR LF
> ```

Answer (score 17):

CRLF ("\r\n"), because browsers follow [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4).