# Premature end of script headers: CGI + C++

Tags: c++, apache, cgi

I can't even get a simple test program working with CGI. Here's my code. It works when I run it in the console, but gives the error when I try to run from Apache:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    printf("TEST");
    return 0;
}
```

MakeFile:

```
build: source/main.cpp
    C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp
```

Error:

```
[Thu Mar 22 19:14:23 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: e2.exe
```

Run in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Stephen>C:\wamp\www\e2.exe
Content-type: text/html

TEST
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Solved: Makefile:

```
build: source/main.cpp
    C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp
```

Comment: HTTP line endings are `\r\n`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I would like to know the difference. Any further reading on it?

Comment: No further than the end of the line :-) But seriously, that's just part of the protocol specification. You can read the RFC if you dare.

Comment: Why read RFCs when some cool person can summarize it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5757349/1210546

Comment: Doesn't MinGW use Windows' style line endings? Since the OP is working on Windows, the \n should be translated to CRLF. I've checked with dev-c++ (don't remember which is the C++ compiler behind), and using printf("abc\n\n"); gives me two CRLF, while printf("abc%c%c",13,13); gives me two CR only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Makefile:

```
build: source/main.cpp
    C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -o build/e2.exe source/main.cpp
```

GCC not G++