# why does http use CRLF as line delimiter?

Tags: http, newline, history

As I know, use `LF` as line delimiter is quite popular, but I'm wondering why many text protocol like HTTP, FTP use `CRLF` as its line delimiter?

I don't think these protocols are invented for old typewriters, so is there any historic reason for this? I tried to search it over google and stackoverflow and wikipedia but do not get any reasonable information.

Thanks

Comment: I would say simply because Microsoft Dos and Windows were most popular operating systems, so client programs from these systems were most used. After all home use of unix-like systems is much younger than use of any others.. And who may know why LF was "not good" so Microsoft "insisted" on CRLF in their products?

Comment: Adding on to what @PiotrWadas said ... the spec also [recommends applications be tolerant and accept `LF` line delimiters](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3) so the official status of `CRLF` as the line delimiter doesn't really mean very much. This tolerance is particularly helpful for situations like telnet where you can simply press enter when manually composing a raw message regardless of the OS from which you're working.

Comment: @PiotrWadas but the first machines using http were Unix like (NeXT) also CRLF probably predates use of just CR

Answer (score 19):

CR-LF as newline is the Internet standard, which long predates HTTP; I believe it was originally specified as part of TELNET in [RFC 158](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc158) in 1971. The RFC Editor has a page [explaining some of the history](https://www.rfc-editor.org/old/EOLstory.txt). This is the convention used by other Internet protocols such as FTP and SMTP, so it only makes sense for HTTP to be consistent with them.

Comment: Even new protocols like Redis make use of this CR-LF convention.

Comment: I believe that RFC 5198 "Unicode Format for Network Interchange" is also relevant.

Comment: The RFC Editor EOL history: "Many today use Windows, based on MS-DOS, which came along later and adopted CR LF as its EOL convention.". This is interesting! So, Microsoft did not "invent" CR-LF but adpoted it!

Comment: @eikuh Yes Microsoft 's MS-DOS took it from Digital Research CP/M, which in turn very likely copied it from DEC operating systems (especially, the TOPS-10 operating system for the DEC PDP-10, which Gary Kildall used when writing CP/M). The fact that it is the Internet standard is independent of Microsoft's adoption of it – Microsoft wasn't even founded until 4 years later – but DEC systems were very popular in the early Internet, which may have influenced the choice of CR-LF as the Internet standard