# Why is my Python script giving me an error every time it runs?

Tags: python, json, apache

I checked the server logs and I can't seem to find anything that explains why it's doing this. Every time I load the page I get a "500 Internal Server Error" message. All I'm trying to do is update a JSON file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import json

new_data = {"2": {"title": "what", "date": "tomorrow"}}

with open("jobs.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data.update(new_data)

with open('test.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: works for me. Just make sure `jobs.json` is in the same directory you are running the python script from

Comment: Have you tried using `cgitb.enable()` to turn on tracing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send some content type header first before sending anything, from [Apache's docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html#writing):

> There are two main differences between ``regular'' programming, and CGI programming.
>
> **First, all output from your CGI program must be preceded by a
>   MIME-type header**. This is HTTP header that tells the client what sort
>   of content it is receiving. Most of the time, this will look like:
>
> ```
> Content-type: text/html
> ```

so it would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import json
import sys

new_data = {"2": {"title": "what", "date": "tomorrow"}}

# print "Content-type: application/json\r\n\r\n" to the output stream
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: application/json\r\n\r\n") # read the comment

with open("jobs.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data.update(new_data)

with open('test.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

also check that path to these files and that you write to a writable directory.

Comment: How come it's not updating my JSON then?

Comment: @DougSmith That probably has to do with the paths and/or the right access, try to write full path to writable directory.

Comment: The print should end with `\n\n`, not what you have above.

Comment: @BSH - you are correct, I overlooked the implicit `\n`. But the `\r` is still incorrect.

Comment: @Robᵩ Actually the correct form is `\r\n\r\n`, [HTTP header line break style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style).

Comment: Yes, but HTTP is not CGI. The correct form for a CGI script is `\n\n`, according to [the document you cited](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html#writing). According to [RFC3875](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-2.2), lines are ended with the system-dependent new line sequence. In Python, that is always '\n'. Regardless, if you run your script on Windows, you'll get CR CR NL CR CR NL on the output stream, which neither of us claim is correct.

Comment: @Robᵩ The document doesn't seem to follow the standard here. Apache tolerates `\n\n` and fixes it to `\r\n\r\n`, from [Apache: The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch04_02.htm): "*A CGI script consists of headers and a body. Everything up to the first blank line (**strictly speaking, CRLF CRLF, but Apache will tolerate LF LF**) is header, and everything else is body.*". In Windows you will get `\r\n\r\n`, and if you used `\n\n` it will be fixed to `\r\n\r\n`, this is a [test case](http://codepad.org/vDXyE5Os).