# python CGI failure, succeeding in perl

Tags: python, cgi

I am trying to use python CGI scripting on my server. Both the python and perl scripts displayed below are in the same directory, with permission 755.

If I try a python hello world using this code, and point the browser to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "Hello, World!"
```

It fails with: `Error 500: Premature end of script headers: cgiwrap`

**I think I have a `cgiwrap` permission issue, as my server is apache, and I read that the `-w` option in perl could bypass that kind of issue.**

Interestingly, I tried with the perl Hello World provided on the host provider help page (which fails when run as is):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello World";
```

It fails with: `CGIWrap Error: Script Execution Failed, Error Message: No such file or directory`

While if I try to execute (only changing the shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "Hello World";
```

it runs...

Furthermore, the command `python index.py` in Terminal runs as expected, while `./index.py` fails with `No such file or directory`

---

The `which python` command output: `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Having no experience with cgi, I wonder if you need to explicitly print the `<html>` and `<body>` tags before rendering any actual content.

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong type of newline when printing the blank line after "Content-type". Try `print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"`

Comment: @BhargavRao I tried, yes. Maybe I am doing it wrong? I edited to try all of your suggestions. BTW, thanks to all for the help, it's really nice of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally seems that I had Windows-style end-of-lines... Although I do not understand how that happened, since the files never travelled through  a Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the default Python in the system is Python 3, not Python 2. In this case, the `print` statements will make the script fail with a syntax error.

Can you check the wbe server's logs? Maybe there is a backtrace detailing what went wrong.

Anyway, to be safe from that, place on the second line of your script
`from __future__ import print_function`, and add parenthesis around the strings following the prints.

(btw, the line endings should be ok for a CGI - check [HTTP header line break style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style) )

One other possible problem is that your web-server is not configured to run `.py` files as CGI programs - check its configuration.

Also, this program should work from the terminal, as it is - try to just run it from the terminal, and see if it prints-out the desired output - if not, check the error messages and correct it. You likely have a syntax error in there, either due to the "print" issue, or maybe incorrect indentation, or other thing we can't see in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried `from __future__ import print_function`. Unfortunately, it does not change the result. I checked, the server does handle `.py`. When run in the terminal, it outputs as expected, with no errors. That is what is killing me, because it means that the interpreter is found and executes the script!