# HTTP POST using Arduino ESP8266 SparkFun Shield

Tags: http, post, get, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to send a POST HTTP to a local server running node.js. The GET request works well. The POST using Postman (local) works well, I don't have any firewall. But I can't run it with Arduino.

The code I'm using is a simple SparkFun Client example in which I only changed GET to POST:

```
void clientDemo() {
  // To use the ESP8266 as a TCP client, use the 
  // ESP8266Client class. First, create an object:
  ESP8266Client client;

  // ESP8266Client connect([server], [port]) is used to 
  // connect to a server (const char * or IPAddress) on
  // a specified port.
  // Returns: 1 on success, 2 on already connected,
  // negative on fail (-1=TIMEOUT, -3=FAIL).
  int retVal = client.connect(destServer, 5000);
  if (retVal == -1) {
    Serial.println(F("Time out"));
    return;
  } else if(retVal == -3) {
    Serial.println(F("Fail connection"));
    return;
  } else if(retVal == 1) {
    Serial.println("Connected with server!");
  }

  // print and write can be used to send data to a connected
  // client connection.
  client.print(httpPost);

  // available() will return the number of characters
  // currently in the receive buffer.
  while (client.available())
    Serial.write(client.read()); // read() gets the FIFO char

  // connected() is a boolean return value - 1 if the 
  // connection is active, 0 if it's closed.
  if (client.connected())
    client.stop(); // stop() closes a TCP connection.
}
```

And the httpPost is:

```
const String httpPost = "POST /meteo HTTP/1.1\n"
                        "Host: 192.168.0.131:5000\n"
                        "User-Agent: Arduino/1.0\n"
                        "Connection: close\n"
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\n"
                          "windspeedmph=0&winddir=0&humidity=0&temp=0&pressure=0\n";
```

All I get in the serial monitor is "Connected with server!"...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an empty line between the headers and body:

```c++
const String httpPost =   "POST /meteo HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                          "Host: 192.168.0.131:5000\r\n"
                          "User-Agent: Arduino/1.0\r\n"
                          "Connection: close\r\n"
                          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n"
                          "\r\n"
                          "windspeedmph=0&winddir=0&humidity=0&temp=0&pressure=0\n";
```

Also by standard you should use `\r\n` for line breaks and not just `\n`.
[HTTP header line break style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. Still only "Connected with server!" and nothing more. I don't even see any POST attempts in logs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was also important to **specify Content-Length field**. Then the application started to work as it should. Without the Content-Length field no data was visible on the receiver side. The Content-Length specifies the length of the payload, in your case the length of the string: "windspeedmph=0&winddir=0&humidity=0&temp=0&pressure=0\n".