# Python: split HTTP headers with .splitlines() vs .split("\r\n")

Tags: python, http, http-headers

How should I split HTTP headers in Python? Using `.splitlines()` or `.split("\r\n")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style) answer shows that "\r\n" is the correct for the HTTP specification, but it is recommended to be ready to accept only "\n" as well in case you receive a header that doesn't follow the specification.

With that in mind, choose `.splitlines`, since [the Python docs say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines.

And also [explains](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

> `universal newlines`: 
>   A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Windows convention '\r\n', and the old Macintosh convention '\r'.

Comment: As mentioned under "universal newlines", `bytes.splitlines()` also splits on `\r`, without any `\n`. I'm not sure that behavior meets the HTTP spec.