# Analogue of vbCr (Carriage return) in Environment

Tags: .net, vb.net, newline, symbols

I found `vbCrLf` has it's analogue (or copy) in `Environment` namespace in VB.net. As I understood there is no difference between them except `vbCrLf` is harder for reading when `Environment.NewLine` is clear.

But I can't find any comfortable analogue of `vbCr` in `Environment`. I checked all the methods but still can't find.

Is there any comfortable for reading analogue of `vbCr` in VB.net?

P.S. Why they create analogue for new line symbol but forget about this one?

Comment: I can't really answer why they did not create an analogue for `vbCr`, but...why bother? you can just add something like `Const CarriageReturn As Char = Chr(13)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why they create analogue for new line symbol but forget about this one?

They did not create an analogue for the new line symbol.

The `Environment.NewLine` is platform-dependent and will be different on different platforms. You use it e.g. when you want to generate human-readable text and therefore want the "whatever the newline symbol is, I don't care what it is exactly".

The `vbCrLf` is not platform-dependent, it's `\r\n` on all platforms. You use that when you are dealing with data contracts that specify there must be an `\r\n` (e.g. forming or reading HTTP headers, these are [separated with `\r\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757349/11683)).

They are not interchangeable and you are supposed to pick the one that is correct for the given purpose.

Personally I like how `vbCrLf` and `vbCr` look and have no problems with them. If you think otherwise, you can confuse future readers of your code by [defining custom constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134942/analogue-of-vbcr-carriage-return-in-environment#comment73347634_43134942) named the way you like.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I am still a newbie in VB.net, but I like to use `Environment.NewLine`