# HTTP Create correct request for an html file in python

Tags: python, sockets, http, https, http-headers

So i've been spending some time trying to learn how to write http request

my goal is to request the html of a web page parse and extract data from there

Im having trouble understanding how I can do this if i dont have the exact path to the file and all i have is the basic url like www.google.com

in a way im trying to do what urllib.request does but manually with socket programming in python

```
#Playing with Sockets

import socket

target_port=80
target_url ='www.google.com'

client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_url,target_port))


request= "GET https://www.google.com HTTP/1.1\nHost:google.com\n\n"

message= request.encode()
client.send(message)

response=client.recv(4096)
print(response.decode())
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I don't have the exact path to the file". The URL *is* the exact path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your HTTP request should use the new line separators `\r\n` (hex values `0x0D` and `0x0A`).  You're only using `\n` (`0x0A`).  [Here's a good stackoverflow question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style).

Second, the path to the request file is relative to the host address.  So when you call `client.connect((target_url,target_port))` to connect to the host's HTTP server, it is ready to accept your request using a relative path.

Ultimately, your request should look like this

`request= "GET /path/to/file.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:google.com\r\n\r\n"`

You will probably need some additional headers in there as well.

Take a look [here](https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1clients) for more information.  If that link doesn't take you to the correct section, I was talking particularly about the `HTTP 1.1 Clients` section.  The `Sample HTTP Exchange` section is great also.  Actually, you will probably find the whole page to be very useful.